# Java Map Contents Upon Garbage Collection Recursive?

Tags: java, list, recursion, dictionary, garbage-collection

I use a structure like the following:

```
HashMap < EnumA , HashMap < Integer , LinkedList < EnumB > > > OverallMap
```

If I were to do this:

```
OverallMap . clear ( )
```

Will everything that was discarded by the `clear()` (the HashMap objects, the Integer objects, and the LinkedList objects) eventually get garbage-collected, or do I have to iterate all the way down to the lists and call clear() on them before `clear()`ing the inner maps and then `clear()`ing the outer map?

Comment: Depends on if the inner maps are reachable from other data structures in the program.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as nothing else references those other objects they will be garbage collected.

Comment: What do you mean by `nothing references`? If I have object `a` that refers to object `b`, and same object `b` refers to object `a`, You want to say that the objects `a` and `b` will never be garbage collected?

Comment: Suppose there was another 'live' collection that refers to one of your nested objects, and you cleared the nested object out of your first collection. It would not be eligible for collection. However, if there's a group of objects that refer to each other in some way, but nothing refers to them, then that group can be collected.

Comment: @CAMOBAP - do you know what a reference is in Java?  Well, basically, if the running application can (still) find a reference to some object, then the object is REACHABLE ... which is the term that Bill should have used.

Comment: @StephenC I know what a reference in Java, also I know that even if  reference to object exists it may be UNREACHABLE (as result it maybe collected), correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I just want to talk that `nothing references` not good statement, better to use `unreachable`

Comment: This is actually good, because I had no idea Java was able to detect a case of unreachability for a circular reference, and I had just assumed that would be a memory leak. That's useful information and makes some other code easier.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is call `clear()` at the top level, unless these collection are referenced  elsewhere but you can only clear them in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, everything but some OverallMap internals will be garbage-collected if you use .clear().